# Rails 4 Ajax NoMethodError - undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass: in my create.js.erb file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I'm trying to render a partial when a button is clicked. I believe I'm doing something obviously wrong... and I expect it's **not** going to be in the following:

```
$('#modrequest').empty();
$('#modrequest').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'moderator_requests/links')).html_safe %>");
```

The error is

> NoMethodError - undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass:

I expect I'm doing something wrong elsewhere, but I'm not sure where, so instead of posting a ton of code, I'll post any file requested.

Thanks

Comment: you are getting this error after ajax is called? Can you post your ajax method and partial you are rendering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Error**

The error will likely be a result of you calling unset data in your `partial`:

```
#partial
<%= item.id %>
```

--

**Fix**

Because you have to pass [local variables to your partials](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables), you're not passing any - which will prevent it from calling the data it needs. You'll be able to resolve the issue like this:

```
$('#modrequest').html("<%=j render(:partial => 'moderator_requests/links', locals: {your: "local"}).html_safe %>");
```

If your data is not able to be passed to your partial, you'll be much better putting it into a [`helper`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers.html), which will allow you to populate it in any part of your app

--

**Definition**

> NoMethodError - undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

This error basically means you're trying to call `id` on a non-existent piece of data. You'll either need to show the partial, or determine which data you're trying to call in the partial

To fix this, you basically need to be able to pass the right data to your partial; either by way of `local` variables, or with a `helper`

Comment: Brilliant, that's perfect, thank you. I was able to pass information as local vars to the partial. Out of interest, at what point would you consider switching to a helper method? My partial only required an object ID, so it wasn't a big issue, but I'd like to be able to use helper methods for this too.

Comment: I'd use a helper if you needed to use the same data in other parts of the app. A good example would be the use of a `nav` bar (if you're calling data from a db across the whole app for the nav bar)